# How to make Chatter Desktop autorefresh more frequently

Tags: chatter

Chatter Desktop automatically refreshes every 5 minutes.  When you're talking about a live conversation, that is ludicrously slow.  Most email servers are faster.

Is there a way to make Chatter Desktop autorefresh faster?

Answer (score 1):

At this point is is currently not possible.

Feel free to vote up this idea though:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000knnzAAA

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Salesforce has a pilot called Salesforce Desktop which refreshes more often but you will need to contact your Customer Success Manager to try to get access to it.